# PCL point Cloud Error in point_types.h

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, printer-control-language

I am trying to get PCL 1.6.0 to work with Visual Studio 2013.

I used the pre-compiled libraries available here: 
[precompiledlibraries](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/windows.html)

I used the Windows MSVC 2010 (64bit) version.

After getting everything linked and loaded, i tried to run a sample code from the tutorials on the PCL website. 
But every code i try to run, it fails on the header files itself.

I keep on getting this error

```
Error   2   error C4996: 'pcl::SHOT': USE SHOT352 FOR SHAPE AND SHOT1344 FOR SHAPE+COLOR INSTEAD    C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl\impl\point_types.hpp 1008    1   pcl
Error   3   error C4996: 'pcl::SHOT': USE SHOT352 FOR SHAPE AND SHOT1344 FOR SHAPE+COLOR INSTEAD    C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl\impl\point_types.hpp 1009    1   pcl
Error   4   error C4996: 'pcl::SHOT::rf': USE SHOT352 FOR SHAPE AND SHOT1344 FOR SHAPE+COLOR INSTEAD    C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl\impl\point_types.hpp 1012    1   pcl
Error   5   error C4996: 'pcl::SHOT::descriptor': USE SHOT352 FOR SHAPE AND SHOT1344 FOR SHAPE+COLOR INSTEAD    C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl\impl\point_types.hpp 1013    1   pcl
Error   6   error C4996: 'pcl::SHOT::descriptor': USE SHOT352 FOR SHAPE AND SHOT1344 FOR SHAPE+COLOR INSTEAD    C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl\impl\point_types.hpp 1014    1   pcl
```

in the header file point_types.h.

I can't figure out how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a pcl 1.6 (installed using all-in-one installer for MSV 2010) with any visual studio version other than VS 2010. You will have to use pcl corresponding to the appropriate VS version. If you do want to use VS 2013, then you compile PCL from source using cmake. (from github)

There are some pre-built PCL1.7 and PCL1.8 all-in-one installers in this website http://unanancyowen.com/?p=1989

Those pcl libraries can be used with VS2013, VS 2015. I downloaded the VS 2013 64 bit PCL 1.8 and now use it in visual studio 2013.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try these.